# How to prevent magento duplicate meta title and meta description on google webmaster tools

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, seo

Anyone please help. 
I'm trying to stop duplicate title and description on Google webmaster tools. 
1. I already turn on Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories and Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products

http://www.siamcase.com/

1. Use Web Server Rewrites >> yes
2. generate a new sitemap >> done
3. block url by robot.txt 
   http://www.siamcase.com/robots.txt

I think i have did everything correctly. But Google webmaster tools still show me a duplicate title and description. I don't know maybe the problem came from a robots.txt or not.

I have updated my `robot.txt` last week. and Google already get Last updated on Jun 17, 2013
Kindly Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Magento helpdesk problem. Belongs over in magento.stackexchange and is for the most part easily fixed by actually setting page titles and descriptions for product pages and categories. Often seen as to be too much work, most people let it default and end up with duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, it sounds like this is easily fixed by actually setting page titles and descriptions for product pages and categories.

Answer (score 0):

May this helps to check your robots.txt:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/

Inchoo’s recommended Magento robots.txt boilerplate:

```
# Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Dissalow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

Answer (score 0):

Alan Storm is 100% correct, setting product meta titles and descriptions is how it's meant to be.

However if you have a LOT of products/categories in your DB, you can modify corresponding template (normally app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/page/html/head.phtml):

I.e. change

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

to

```
<?php $postfix = (Mage::registry('current_product') ? Mage::registry('current_product')->getName() : (Mage::registry('current_category') ? Mage::registry('current_category')->getName() : '') ); ?>
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() . ' ' . $postfix ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()). ' ' . $postfix ?>" />
```